# Automate clicking in a website and performing tasks

Tags: perl

I want to add my email as an allowed email address to those who use my program. In amazon i need to follow a set of procedures for making sure that my email address is allowed. I want to know if it is possible to automate this process using a perl module since it is extremely repetitive.
I have to login and then click manage kindle and then a few other buttons as a user . How would i automate this process using a perl script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. You can either use greasemonkey to run a browser script to automate the clicking for you using javascript or you can use your programming language of choice with curl to get the page you need, scrape the data, then resubmit that data via get or post depending on what the site uses. If you know the url for the page to press the final button on, you can make a curl request to log in, then make a curl request to pretend like you just clicked the button on that page. Most of the time you don't need to visit all the pages in-between the two. Sometimes though, you do. Curl can be complex and a bit daunting to new users, but here's a curl module for perl http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Curl If you need to learn how to use it, here's a good resource http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php It's in php, but I think all the functions should be the same as the ones in perl. Amazon shouldn't, but if they do block curl requests, just copy the headers from your browser into curl and use those. Good luck!

Comment: In Perl land, most people prefer [libwww-perl](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl) over libcurl, mostly because LWP does not have an insane C interface.